# What am I missing here - in implementing tabs in my activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tabs, fragmentstatepageradapter

My **MainActivity** class - where I want to implement fixed tabs

```
package com.nikhil.tabs;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // How to add tabs here
       // What more is missing?

            } 

    //Do I need any listeners for tabs here?

}
```

Below is the code for my adapter class. Initially I used `FragmentPagerAdapter` but I had some issues with `ActionBar` in MainActivity. So, now I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

**My Adapter Class**

```
package com.nikhil.tabs;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games"};

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new TopRatedFragment();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new GamesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return tabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

}
```

**If I run my app. I'm not getting any tabs. What is missing please?**

If I try to add

```
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

in my class, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS is getting striked off, because it is deprecated. Still, if I try to run the app, it is getting crashed.

**EDIT :**

**My Logcat:**

```
03-07 23:03:02.350    2970-2970/com.nikhil.tabs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikhil.tabs, PID: 2970
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikhil.tabs/com.nikhil.tabs.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.nikhil.tabs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: what is the logcat? being deprecated doesnt mean it should crash.. there might be some error in the code

Comment: I added Logcat @HirakChhatbar. :)

Comment: have u defined ActionBar actionbar = new ActionBar anywhere?

Comment: Yes, ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

Comment: please send the whole code... also click on "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:" this part on you logcat and see which line it corresponds to

Comment: Thanks for your time @HirakChhatbar. I actually followed this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ The code is all there. But since I cannot use NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS any other simple way out?

Comment: Other solution is using fahim's solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the API 21 the method `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` is deprecated. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)).

If you prefer to have a tabs like google play store style, u can use [PagerSlidingTabStrip library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

Google example for [SlidingTabsBasic](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

Comment: But if I add this. NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS is getting striked off because it is deprecated.

Comment: If I try to run the app, it is crashing @Fahim

Comment: That's good to know, but any idea on how to implement common navigation methods.

Comment: since it is deprecated you can't use with actionbar

Comment: Okay, I don't insist on ActionBar only. Any alternatives, how do people create tabs nowadays @Fahim. I have no idea. That  PagerSlidingTabStrip library itself is 3.8MB. After all I only want two tabs.

Comment: Its of all small size, you have to use from it what you want. and i have added google example for sliding tabs, check the answer